# App stops working when i keep sending multiple messages with socket.io

Tags: node.js, react-native, sockets, socket.io

I have a react native expo CLI app add i am trying to create a in app built messaging app like whatsapp inside. All my api calls work in storing the messages and get all the conversations. I have an all messages screen is shows all the conversation the user has with the last message sent inside the chat and a chat screen that shows all the messages sent inside that conversation.

I am using `socket.io-client` and everything works accordingly except when I keep sending multiple messages my backend stops connecting to my app, then I need to reload my app again then the same happens. Why is that happening?

Also, something is wrong with my code, the messages are getting emitted multiple times.

Here is my code

NodeJS

```
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socket(server)

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  // connection
  console.log('User ' + socket.id + ' connected')
  
  // joining a room
  socket.on('subscribe', (room) => {
    console.log('user socket', socket.id, 'joining room', room);
    socket.join(room);
  });

  // send message within room
  socket.on('message', (data) => {
    io.in(data.conversationId).emit('send_message', { 
      message: data.message,
      receiverId: data.to,
      senderId: data.from,
      id: data.conversationId,
      data: data.data
    });
  })

  // seen message
  socket.on('markSeen', (data) => {
    // Emit 'markedSeen' event
    console.log(socket.id, 'has seen your message')
    io.emit('markedSeen', data);
  });

  // main socket listening
  socket.on('listening', (data) => {
    console.log(data)
    console.log('user socket', socket.id, 'is listening', data.conversationId, data.message)
    io.emit('socketListening', data)
  });

  // user typing within room
  socket.on('typing', (data) => {
    console.log('user socket', socket.id, 'in room', data.chatId, data.text)
    io.in(data.chatId).emit('typingResponse', data.text)
  });

  // waiting to enter room
  socket.on('waiting', (data) => {
    console.log('user', socket.id, 'is waiting.');
  });

  // disconnect
  socket.on('disconnect',() => {
    console.log('USER DISCONNECTED', socket.id)
  })

  socket.on('unsubscribe', (data) => {
    console.log(data)
    socket.leave(data.id);
    socket.to(data.id).emit('user left', socket.id);  
    console.log('user left', socket.id)
  });
})
```

React Native

Messages Screen

```
const [listings, setListings] = useState([]);
const [error, setError] = useState(false);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);

const loadListings = async() => {
  setLoading(true);
  const response = await messagesApi.getMessages();
  setLoading(false);
  if(refreshing) setRefreshing(false);
  if (!response.ok) return setError(true);
  setError(false);
  setListings(response.data)
};

const { user } = useAuth();

const socketUrl = 'IP_ADDRESS';
let socket = useRef(null);

useEffect(()=>{
  loadListings();

  socket.current = io.connect(socketUrl)

  socket.current.on('connect', msg => {
    console.log(`user: ${user.id} is waiting.`)
    console.log(`user: ${user.id} is waiting. socketID: ${socket.current.id}`)
    socket.current.emit('waiting', user.id);
  });

  return(() => {
    console.log(`user: ${user.id} --- socketid ${socket.current.id} deleted`)
    socket.current.removeAllListeners('connect')
  });
}, [socketUrl])

useEffect(() => {
  socket.current.on("socketListening", (msg) => {
  console.log('MSG',msg)

  const result = listings.find(e => e.id === msg.conversationId)

  if (result !== undefined) {
    const resultMessages = result.Messages;
    const newMessages = [msg,...resultMessages]
    result.Messages = newMessages;
    result.lastMessage = msg.message;
    const arraywithoutrecord = listings.filter(e=>e.id!=msg.conversationId)
    setListings([result,...arraywithoutrecord])
  }
})
   
  socket.current.on('markedSeen', (message) => {
    const result = listings?.find(e => e.id === message)
    if (result !== undefined) {
      result.Messages[0].seenByUser = true;
      const arraywithoutrecord = listings?.filter(e=>e.id!=message)
      setListings([result,...arraywithoutrecord])
    }
  });
}, [listings]);
```

Chat Screen

```
const message = route.params.message;

const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);
const [text, setText] = useState('');
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const [error, setError] = useState(false);
const[isAdminTyping, setIsAdminTyping] = useState(false)

const { user } = useAuth();

const socketUrl = 'IP_ADDRESS';
let socket = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
  setMessages(message.Messages)

  socket.current = io.connect(socketUrl)

  socket.current.on('connect', msg => {
    console.log(`user: ${user.id} has joined conversation ${message.id}`,'connection socket id', socket.current.id)
    socket.current.emit('subscribe', message.id);
    socket.current.emit('markSeen', message.id);
  });

  socket.current.on("send_message", (msg) => {
    setMessages(messages => [msg, ...messages]);
    socket.current.emit('markSeen', message.id);
  });

  socket.current.on("typingResponse", (msg) => {
    if (msg === 'Admin is typing...') {
      setIsAdminTyping(true)
    } else {
      setIsAdminTyping(false)
    }
  })
     
  return(() => {
    console.log(`user: ${user.id} left the room ${message.id} --- socketid ${socket.current.id}`)
    socket.current.close()
  });
}, [socketUrl]);

const seenByUser = async () => {
  const response = await messagesApi.seenByUser({conversationId:message.id});
  if (response.ok) {
    console.log('all messages seen')
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  seenByUser();
},[messages])

const onSend = async(conversationId, senderId, receiverId, message) => {
  const response = await messagesApi.sendMessage({ conversationId, senderId, receiverId, message });
  if (!response.ok) return setError(true);
  console.log("sent")
  const to = (user.id === route.params.message.user ?route.params.message.admin : route.params.message.user)
  socket.current.emit('message', { to: to, from: user.id, message, conversationId, data: response.data });
  setText("")       
  socket.current.emit('listening',response.data);
};

const onFocus = () => {
  socket.current.emit('typing', { chatId: message.id, text: 'User is typing...' });
}

const onBlur = () => {
  socket.current.emit('typing', { chatId: message.id, text: 'User is NOT typing...' });
}
```

My entire Node index.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const users = require("./routes/users");
const auth = require("./routes/auth");
const listing = require("./routes/listing");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const compression = require("compression");
const config = require("config");
const app = express();

var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())

//Socket.io
const http = require("http");
const socket = require("socket.io")

const server=http.createServer(app);

const io =socket(server,
  {
  cors: {
    origin:
    [
      "http://localhost:3000", /\.localhost\:3000$/,"IP_ADDRESS"
      
    ]
    ,
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    credentials: true
},
maxHttpBufferSize: 4e6 // 4Mb
}
)


io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
  // connection
  console.log('User '+socket.id+' connected')
  
  // joining a room
  socket.on('subscribe', (room)=> {
    console.log('user socket',socket.id,'joining room', room);
    socket.join(room);
  });

  // send message within room
  socket.on('message', (data) => {
    socket.to(data.conversationId).emit('send_message', { 
      message: data.message, receiverId: data.to,senderId:data.from,id:data.conversationId,data:data.data
    });
  })

  // seen message
  socket.on('markSeen', (data)=> {
    // Emit 'markedSeen' event
    console.log(socket.id,'has seen your message')
    io.emit('markedSeen', data);
});


  // main socket listening
  socket.on('listening', (data) => {
    console.log(data)
    console.log('user socket',socket.id,'is listening',data.conversationId,data.message)
    io.emit('socketListening',data)
    }
    );

  // user typing within room
  socket.on('typing', (data) => {
  console.log('user socket',socket.id,'in room',data.chatId,data.text)
  io.in(data.chatId).emit('typingResponse', data.text)
  }
  );

  // waiting to enter room
  socket.on('waiting', (data)=> {
    console.log('user',socket.id, 'is waiting.');
  });

  // disconnect
  socket.on('disconnect',(reason)=>{
    socket.disconnect()    
    console.log('socket disconnected',socket.disconnect().disconnected)
    console.log('USER DISCONNECTED',socket.id)
  })
})

app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true, parameterLimit: 500000}));
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(helmet());
app.use(compression());
app.use("/api/users/", users);
app.use("/api/auth/", auth)
app.use("/api/listings/", listing);

const port = process.env.PORT || config.get("port");

server.listen(port, function() {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${port}...`);
});
```

Comment: Isn't it a problem to keep calling `io.connect(socketUrl)` inside of `useEffect()`?  Won't you be doing it over and over again every time the page is modified?  I don't know React very well, but from the little I've read that seems wrong to me.

Comment: @jfriend00 in react if something is inside the dependancy [] the useeffect gets called everytime that variable not when the page is modified.

Comment: @jfriend00 but is the socket structured correctly?

Comment: @jfriend00 i created a cleaner question if you can please have a look at it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74191884/expo-app-connection-with-nodejs-stops-working-with-sockets

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expo app connection with NodeJS stops working with sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74191884/expo-app-connection-with-nodejs-stops-working-with-sockets)

Answer (score 0):

Cant speak to why it stops connecting, would really need more details on that one. For example, is it 'new' connections, or is your current connection dropping etc.

The whole point of WS is a persistent connection, so, once a user is connected, they should not need to reconnect again (unless they got disconnected)

Without knowing the whole flow of things in your app ( this is just going off what you have posted here )

It looks like you are having a user connect 'each time' they hit that page, if my assumption is correct here, then don't do that :D

This kind of leads into your other question about multiple messages being sent and then ties back into the whole websocket idea in the first place, its a persistent connection so you only need to do thing once.

For example, if you subscribe to a channel or room, you only need to do that one time, once you subscribe to a channel that socketID is tied to those emits, and a socket can subscribe to a channel multiple times. Knowing that, if, when a user hits your messages screen, and your code goes through and subscribes them to that channel each time they will in turn get multiple emits.

Again, without seeing the full flow of data it looks like every time a user hit your chat screen you are attempting to

- connect to socket
- server setting up the on events

Essentially telling them to connect again and listen for those calls, the more times they join, the more they see right.

What you want to do is make sure you define your socket globally AND only 'listen' for channels or emits 'once'

What I have done in the past is to have a main socket function when a user joins the event, this is done on login and or opening the app. This will perform the socket connect, run through all the connections etc and at the end I call a socketInit function. This function sets up all my .on statements in a conditional block, that ensures it will only run one time. So, something like if(socketInit = false) {run all my on code etc}

This ensures everything is only called one time. Then, inside each route, I do the 'emit' to the socket server telling it to 'join the room' or 'getchats' etc. Because I only have the .on called once, it means when I asked the socket server for the data via the emit what it returns on my .on only gets called once, because that .getChat on is only defined once and it knows what to do with that data and updates the screen accordingly.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, thank you for the clarification. Why i have 2 socket connections is the first socket connect opens on the screen that loads all the conversations, this listen to the last message sent inside the chat & whether the message has been seen or not, the 2nd socket connection opens inside the chat to actually listen the messages being sent inside room. I am trying to build an inapp message exactly like whatsapp, where you have 2 screens. 1) All Chats Screen -new message, see read and unread messages,last message sent  2)Chat Screen - all messages sent

Comment: Can the same socket listen to multiple events on different screens at the same time?

Comment: I mean, technically, sockets you are connected to always 'listening' right. Screens are more of a design pattern but the listening sockets would be 'listening' regardless, so, I guess you could be collecting / storing data in like indexeddb and when in view display them, but thats more of a design question

Comment: Hi, ive got a quick question my socket keeps disconnecting after 4 messages have been sent and doesnt reconnect after why is thins happening?